# Tensorflow 2.0 syntax change

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have the following lines of codes that i would like to run and it's written based on the tensorflow 1.0 syntax:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(2)
c = tf.constant(3)
d = tf.multiply(a,b)
e = tf.add(b,c)
f = tf.subtract(d,e)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    fetches = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
    outs = sess.run(fetches)
    print("outs={}".format(outs))
```

But its printing out the error message stating:

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

and after looking up, it seems like tensorflow 2.0 no longer supports sessions, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2

Problem is I do not really understand the documentation as it seemed complex, so what are the changes that I could implement in the code above to obtain the same output in tensorflow 1.0? Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: I think you should try `tf.compat.v1`, it's an easy way to migrate code from tf1.0 to 2.0

Answer (score 1):

try to use `tf.compat.v1.Session` inplace of `Session`
other than this for more doubts you can refer to tensorflow
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984195/converting-tensorflow-1-0-code-to-tensorflow-2-0/68984955#68984955) seems to be the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated code following this [migration document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(2)
c = tf.constant(3)
d = tf.multiply(a,b)
e = tf.add(b,c)
f = tf.subtract(d,e)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    fetches = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
    outs = sess.run(fetches)
    print("outs={}".format(outs))
```