# Converting tensorflow 1.0 code to tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(2)
c = tf.constant(3)
d = tf.multiply(a,b)
e = tf.add(b,c)
f = tf.subtract(d,e)

with tf.Session() as sess: #changes should be made here since session is not supported in 2.0
    fetches = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
    outs = sess.run(fetches)
    print("outs={}".format(outs))
```

Since "session" are no longer supported in tensorflow 2.0, how do i modify it so that it is in tensorflow 2.0 syntax?

I would prefer not using the compat function as I want to learn the new tensorflow 2.0 syntax alternative for session. I read the doc, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2 but I'm having a hard time understanding it on the doc mentioning to use a function instead.

How do i modify the session code above so that i can get the same output in tensorflow 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Since [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) is enabled by default, any operation is calculated immediately.

> Enabling eager execution changes how TensorFlow operations behave—now
> they immediately evaluate and return their values to Python. tf.Tensor
> objects reference concrete values instead of symbolic handles to nodes
> in a computational graph. Since there isn't a computational graph to
> build and run later in a session, it's easy to inspect results using
> print() or a debugger.
>
> Eager execution works nicely with NumPy. NumPy operations accept
> tf.Tensor arguments. The tf.Tensor.numpy method returns the object's
> value as a NumPy ndarray.

So you can call `numpy()` on a tensor to get its numerical value:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(2)
c = tf.constant(3)
d = tf.multiply(a,b)
e = tf.add(b,c)
f = tf.subtract(d,e)

print('outs =', [a.numpy(), b.numpy(), c.numpy(), d.numpy(),
      e.numpy(), f.numpy()])
```